# json decode on some servers converts dots as commas on numbers

Tags: php, json, api

Dots are getting auto replaced with Commas in decimal numbers from JSON API data, when json_decode.

This issue is occurring only on server (may be its European servers, not sure of) not localhost.

```
$x = [99.55];
$y = ['75.45'];

$encoded_x = json_encode($x);
$encoded_y = json_encode($y);

$decoded_x = json_decode($encoded_x);
$decoded_y = json_decode($encoded_y);
```

Output:

```
//$decoded_x
[99,55]

//$decoded_y
['75.45']
```

Comment: `echo locale::getdefault();`

Comment: It's not anything to do with the json decoding, it's the locale setting of your server. You'll want to set it to something that matches what you expect. System level: https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/ PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: We have updated the server locale to fix it.

Comment: OK so mark as accepted if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Different locales use different characters and formats for certain things like decimals, date formats, etc...  Choose the one that formats as you want and set it:

```
Locale::setDefault('en-US');
```